# MouseInfo 0.1.3 cannot read RGB pixel values on my iMac: NA_on_macOS

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014), Screen Size: 2560 x 1440
macOS Big Sur 11.7.10
MouseInfo 0.1.3
Pillow version 8.0.1
PyAutoGUI version 0.9.52
Python 3.12.0

MouseInfo cannot read RGB pixel values correctly:

RGB color shows 'NA_on_macOS'
RGB as Hex shows 'NA_on_macOS'
Color field is dark black

Expected correct RGB values and correct color field.

How can I fix that?

The rest works (although F-keys are not displayed anymore after first usage of a button).